# Python - Script reads one value from JSON and writes it 200 times in CSV

Tags: python, json

I am writing a Python script which reads data from multiple JSON files and writes it into a single output CSV file. I've written some code but it is not correct. I've formatted JSON for simplicity here otherwise it's on a single line. Each "requestId" contains multiple "id" values. My current code is able to read only one "id" and repeats it 200 times. Not sure why this is happening.

***JSON File***

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "requestId":"3561c",
   "result":[  
      {  
         "id":257268,
         "name":"02 ",
         "description":"",
         "createdAt":"2017-10-06T11:29:40Z+0000",
         "updatedAt":"2017-11-07T13:38:11Z+0000",
         "url":"https",
         "subject":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"Are you ready"
         },
         "fromName":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"Centre"
         },
         "fromEmail":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"abc@xyz.com"
         },
         "replyEmail":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"noreply@xwz.com"
         },
         "folder":{  
            "type":"Folder",
            "value":8041,
            "folderName":"A"
         },
         "operational":false,
         "textOnly":false,
         "publishToMSI":false,
         "webView":false,
         "status":"approved",
         "template":681,
         "workspace":"R",
         "version":1,
         "autoCopyToText":false
      },
      {  
         "id":257273,
         "name":"02a",
         "description":"",
         "createdAt":"2017-10-06T11:29:46Z+0000",
         "updatedAt":"2017-11-07T13:38:19Z+0000",
         "url":"https:",
         "subject":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"Still have questions?"
         },
         "fromName":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"Centre"
         },
         "fromEmail":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"abc@xyz.com"
         },
         "replyEmail":{  
            "type":"Text",
            "value":"noreply@xwz.com"
         },
         "folder":{  
            "type":"Folder",
            "value":8041,
            "folderName":"A"
         },
         "operational":false,
         "textOnly":false,
         "publishToMSI":false,
         "webView":false,
         "status":"approved",
         "template":681,
         "workspace":"R",
         "version":1,
         "autoCopyToText":false },
```

---

***Python Code***

```
import json
import csv
import os
import codecs
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

file_dir = os.path.normpath('/home/pp/jobs/staging/')
exp_dir = os.path.normpath('/home/pp/jobs/CSV/')
exp_file_name = 'emails.csv'
exp_path = os.path.join(exp_dir, exp_file_name)


my_dict_list =[]
try:
    for f in os.listdir(file_dir):
        if f.endswith('.json') and f.startswith('emails_'):
            file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, f)
            data = open(file_path, 'r')
            for line in data:
                my_dict = {}
                parsed_data = json.loads(line)
                my_dict["REQUEST_ID"] = parsed_data["requestId"]
                my_dict["SUCCESS"] = parsed_data["success"]
                for result in parsed_data["result"]:
                    my_dict["RESULT_ID"] = result["id"]
                    my_dict["NAME"] = result["name"]
                    my_dict["DESCRIPTION"] = result.get("description")
                    my_dict["STATUS"] = result["status"].encode('utf-8')
                    my_dict["FOLDER_TYPE"] = result["folder"]["type"]
                    my_dict["FOLDER_ID"] = result["folder"]["value"]
                    my_dict["FOLDER_NAME"] = result["folder"]["folderName"]
                    my_dict["FROM_EMAIL_TYPE"] = result["fromEmail"]["type"]
                    my_dict["FROM_EMAIL_VALUE"] = result["fromEmail"]["value"]
                    my_dict["FROM_NAME_TYPE"] = result["fromName"]["type"]
                    my_dict["FROM_NAME_VALUE"] = result["fromName"]["value"]
                    my_dict["REPLY_EMAIL_TYPE"] = result["replyEmail"]["type"]
                    my_dict["REPLY_EMAIL_VALUE"] = result["replyEmail"]["value"]
                    my_dict["SUBJECT_TYPE"] = result["subject"]["type"]
                    my_dict["SUBJECT_VALUE"] = result["subject"]["value"]
                    my_dict["OPERATIONAL"] = result["operational"]
                    my_dict["PUBLISH_TO_MSI"] = result["publishToMSI"]
                    my_dict["TEMPLATE"] = result["template"]
                    my_dict["TEXT_ONLY"] = result["textOnly"]
                    my_dict["URL"] = result.get("url")
                    my_dict["WEBVIEW"] = result["webView"]
                    my_dict["CREATED_AT"] = result["createdAt"]
                    my_dict["UPDATED_AT"] = result["updatedAt"]
                    my_dict["WORKSPACE"] = result["workspace"]
                    my_dict_list.append(my_dict)

    csv_columns = ["REQUEST_ID","SUCCESS","RESULT_ID","NAME","DESCRIPTION","STATUS","FOLDER_TYPE","FOLDER_ID","FOLDER_NAME","FROM_EMAIL_TYPE","FROM_EMAIL_VALUE","FROM_NAME_TYPE","FROM_NAME_VALUE","REPLY_EMAIL_TYPE","REPLY_EMAIL_VALUE","SUBJECT_TYPE","SUBJECT_VALUE","OPERATIONAL","PUBLISH_TO_MSI","TEMPLATE","TEXT_ONLY","URL","WEBVIEW","CREATED_AT","UPDATED_AT","WORKSPACE"]
    with open(exp_path,'wb') as csvfile:
                   xz = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=csv_columns)
                   headers = {}
                   for n in xz.fieldnames:
                       headers[n] = n
                   xz.writerow(headers)
                   for data in my_dict_list:
                       xz.writerow(data)
except Exception as exception:
    print("Please check the logs. JSON to CSV conversion failed for Emails: ", exception)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at here:

```
my_dict_list =[]
try:
    for f in os.listdir(file_dir):
        if f.endswith('.json') and f.startswith('emails_'):
            file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, f)
            data = open(file_path, 'r')
            for line in data:
                my_dict = {}
                parsed_data = json.loads(line)
                # ...
                for result in parsed_data["result"]:
                    # ...
                    my_dict_list.append(my_dict)
```

The `my_dict` is a dictionary that is renewed only at line level of file. But what you want to do seems to be at each element of `parsed_data["result"]`. If you append the same dict to a list inside a loop and mutate it, you're actually putting multiple identical copies into the list, and when you mutate, you mutate all copies. ("copy" is a bad term in Python here as they are, indeed, just references)

To solve you problem, try replace this:

```
                my_dict_list.append(my_dict)
```

with this:

```
                my_dict_list.append(dict(my_dict))
```

this will make a (shallow) copy before put into the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common gotcha in Python. The important thing here is that my_dict is a pointer to a dict.

What is happening here is that you are defining my_dict (a pointer to a dict), updating it with a set of values and then appending it to a list. Then in the second iteration of the loop you change the values of my_dict and append this to the second position in the array. However, my_dict is also in the first position of the array. So values of the my_dict are now updated in both index 0 and index 1 of the array.

Because of this all values are updated in every dict in the list, not just the Id. This continues till the last iteration of the loop when all entries in the list (they are all my_dict) are updated to the values of the last dict in result.

One way to fix this is to define a new dict in every iteration.

```
        for line in data:
            parsed_data = json.loads(line)
            for result in parsed_data["result"]:
                my_dict = {}
                my_dict["REQUEST_ID"] = parsed_data["requestId"]
                my_dict["SUCCESS"] = parsed_data["success"]

                my_dict["RESULT_ID"] = result["id"]
                my_dict["NAME"] = result["name"]
                my_dict["DESCRIPTION"] = result.get("description")
                my_dict["STATUS"] = result["status"].encode('utf-8')
                my_dict["FOLDER_TYPE"] = result["folder"]["type"]
                my_dict["FOLDER_ID"] = result["folder"]["value"]
                my_dict["FOLDER_NAME"] = result["folder"]["folderName"]
                my_dict["FROM_EMAIL_TYPE"] = result["fromEmail"]["type"]
                my_dict["FROM_EMAIL_VALUE"] = result["fromEmail"]["value"]
                my_dict["FROM_NAME_TYPE"] = result["fromName"]["type"]
                my_dict["FROM_NAME_VALUE"] = result["fromName"]["value"]
                my_dict["REPLY_EMAIL_TYPE"] = result["replyEmail"]["type"]
                my_dict["REPLY_EMAIL_VALUE"] = result["replyEmail"]["value"]
                my_dict["SUBJECT_TYPE"] = result["subject"]["type"]
                my_dict["SUBJECT_VALUE"] = result["subject"]["value"]
                my_dict["OPERATIONAL"] = result["operational"]
                my_dict["PUBLISH_TO_MSI"] = result["publishToMSI"]
                my_dict["TEMPLATE"] = result["template"]
                my_dict["TEXT_ONLY"] = result["textOnly"]
                my_dict["URL"] = result.get("url")
                my_dict["WEBVIEW"] = result["webView"]
                my_dict["CREATED_AT"] = result["createdAt"]
                my_dict["UPDATED_AT"] = result["updatedAt"]
                my_dict["WORKSPACE"] = result["workspace"]
                my_dict_list.append(my_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks @amanbirs. Your explanation makes sense and resolved the problem. What is the difference between creating a new list(your approach) and what **Adrian Tam** posted below. Both the solutions worked fine.

Comment: In my example, I am defining a new dictionary at the start of the result loop. Adrian is using the same dictionary, but making a copy when appending to the list thereby inserting different dictionaries at different indices in the list. Both are valid, just comes down to style.

Comment: Thanks again @amanbirs. I was thinking of adding exception handling in this particular block. I want to write my_dict["REQUEST_ID"]  and my_dict["RESULT_ID"] values to log file if any error occurs in data. Something like this but not sure if this is accurate:  
                    `except ValueError:
                        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                        logger.info("Request ID {my_dict['REQUEST_ID']} and Result ID {my_dict['SUCCESS']}", exc_info=True)`

Comment: @django-unchained not sure if I understand the question. Maybe make it a new post so you can explain it clearly and other people can also suggest answers?

Comment: Here it is: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338125/how-to-write-data-values-in-log-file-if-keyerror-or-valueerror-is-raised?noredirect=1#comment91623867_52338125]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you read lines from the file since it's already one line per file anyway?
This part:

```
data = open(file_path, 'r')
    for line in data:
        my_dict = {}
        parsed_data = json.loads(line)
```

can be reduced to:

```
my_dict = {}
parsed_data = json.loads(open(file_path, 'r').read())
```